# What Authentication Type to use for Solace Client Cert Authentication?

Tags: solace

If I want to use client cert authentication, what Authentication Type (None/Internal) should I use?  Do I have to create a user in Solace to user client cert authentication?

Answer (score 2):

To implement client certificate authentication for clients connecting to a Solace appliance, you should use the client-certificate authentication feature.

The authentication types that you have mentioned (None/Internal) are all options for configuring basic authentication. If you wish to use client certificates, you should not configure basic authentication and configure client certificate authentication instead.

You can set the Message VPN to use client-certificate authentication with the following CLI commands:

```
solace(config)# message-vpn <vpn-name>
solace(config-msg-vpn)# authentication user-class client
solace(config-msg-vpn-auth-user-class-client)# client-certificate
```

You will have to create a client username account for the client. Client username accounts are used to provide authenticated clients with predefined client configurations (client profile, ACL profile). By default, when a client authenticates with a client certificate, the common name (CN) in a client certificate’s subject is used as the client username. Alternatively, you can configure the Message VPN to use a client username that the client provides through a session property.

Comment: Even to use client certificate authentication, I have to create a client username account.  So, this will also subject to the limit of 200K usernames in one Solace appliance?

Comment: There is a limit of 200K client connections on one Solace appliance. This limit is for the number of clients that have authenticated and are connected to the appliance and the client username accounts are not associated with this limit.

There is a limit of 9000 client username accounts that you can create on the appliance. Any number of clients can share a client username.